# Facebook Graph API intermittent 500 response, error code -3 when posting videos

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I sometimes get the following error message from v2.4 of the Facebook Graph API when making a POST request to `page/videos` endpoint:

```
ApiResponseCode: 500
ApiExceptionType: FacebookGraphException
ApiErrorMessage: Received Facebook error response of type : Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request (code -3, subcode null)
```

Note that this is restFB's Java version of the exception, which as far as I know simply parses the HTTP response into a `FacebookGraphException`

This is an intermittent issue and represents a very small percentage of our daily calls to this endpoint. I'm guessing this is something to do with API rate limiting but I can't be sure as we usually get a different error message, with code 4 (not -3), for rate limiting as per the [following documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting#applimit)

Any help in debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated! I can't find anything online relating to this error code.
Thanks

-- EDIT

I'm using the [resumable upload](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads#resumable) protocol in an attempt to post videos using the Graph API. The videos in question are all way under 1.75GB in size and much less than 45min in length

-- EDIT 2

Looks like this has gotten a tiny bit of attention as the error code has changed from -3 to 1. The full response now being: `Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request (code 1, subcode null)`

Comment: Can you please give some information what you are posting. Facebook allows to use `post` instead of get if the query is very long. And the error message points in that direction.

Comment: I am attempting to post a video (less than 1.75GB and 45min in length) to a Facebook page using the resumable upload method of the Facebook Graph API as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads#resumable

Comment: Already tried the resumable upload as documented here? http://restfb.com/#publishing-big-video

Comment: Yes that's pretty much exactly what we're doing. Did I mention that this works 90% of the time but only fails for a single Facebook Page? In that sense I don't really need help with the code but was wondering if anyone has come across this before as that error code and message isn't documented anywhere.

I've submitted a request to Facebook, so they'll hopefully respond with something useful that I can put in here :)

Comment: I see, I think you did the right thing with open an issue at Facebook.

Comment: There was a rumour that Facebook engineers look at SO, hence why I put the question on here but I guess this remains a myth! :P

Comment: We (facebook engineers) always try to keep an eye on SO questions. I would say this is either an intermittent issue or a bug if this is only happening to a single page. I would add your bug report here as a comment or answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I managed to catch your attention! I feel like I should apologise for my dirty tactics, I understand that you guys can't be everywhere at once. Is there any chance you could dig into what this error code means or is quite a generic one? I didn't open a bug report as this issue is hard to replicate but I was assured someone is looking into it. I'll update this if I hear anything back but in any case your help would be very much appreciated :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was confirmed as a bug by Facebook and a fix has been pushed. They did not provide any additional technical details

Comment: Is there a source document I can reference where Facebook acknowledges the bug?

Comment: Yes sorry, I should have put it on here a while ago: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/682222548584673

Comment: Thanks for the link.